# Importing a large table from a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, analytics

I'm trying to write a tool (using python, I don't think this is relevant for this question) to transform and move data from a production replica running in AWS RDS to an analytics database hosted outside AWS, both PostgreSQL.

My challenge is, on the initial run, when I have to fetch the entire data set some tables are extremely large (~28M rows). This unfortunately gets cancelled by the database with:

```
canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
```

There are a couple of options I have discovered:

1. I can tweak the `max_standby_streaming_delay` like described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280716/error-canceling-statement-due-to-conflict-with-recovery
   Problem I have with this solution is that this is a high-transaction system during certain hours of the day, and I'm afraid it might degrade performance. Based on my understanding, this would be the case if I increase `max_standby_streaming_delay`. Is this assumption correct?
2. Implement some sort of paging mechanism, so my SELECT query is limited to a certain number of rows. Before I start implementing this I want to see if there are better options.
3. Do an export then import using pgsql then have the tool run for fetching only recent batches of data. I don't prefer this option as it relies on a manual step and I'd rather have the tool capable of fetching the entire data set if needed.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) and since using Python is relevant and assuming you are using `psycopg2` then use it's built in [copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) support.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing max_standby_streaming_delay will not degrade performance on the master.  It will cause the standby to stall replay for while (up to the duration of the max_standby_streaming_delay), meaning other connections will see some stale data.  I guess you could consider that a performance degradation, but that would be an unconventional way to describe it.

And that will only happen when the increased delay is actually kicking in. So if the only "canceling statement" you ever see is the one you are now talking about, then that is the only time other sessions will see stale data (that is, more stale than usual).

My preferred option here would be to just run the export on the master.  It could decrease the master's performance, but you could choose to run the export at the quietest time of the day, when it should have some extra capacity.

I don't see why you describe option 3 as being manual.  It can be automated just as well as anything else can be.